# Xcode 4.6 won't archive a target with dependent libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.6

Trying to archive a target results in dependent libraries being unable to find public header files during compile. I am seeing an error like this during Archive.

```
fatal error: 'OmniBase/NSException-OBExtensions.h' file not found
#import <OmniBase/NSException-OBExtensions.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to Xcode 4.6 not escaping header search paths properly. No matter how hard I try to escape the search path it is always split at the space. This issue did not appear in previous versions of Xcode. I was able to correct this issue by removing the space from the Scheme Name that I was building with.

It seems the only way to correct this problem is to make sure your search path has no spaces. You can inspect your search paths by looking at the compile arguments in the Error Log. Every argument starting with `-I` is a search path.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the header search path in quotes:

```
"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../path/to/headers"
```